# How to replace square brackets without removing contents of brackets

Tags: php, wordpress

Apologies if I’ve missed something basic here - I’ve got a function that *should* replace any square brackets in my WordPress content with less than/greater than tags:

```
function configure_apple_content( $content ) {
    $remov = array("[", "]");
    $replc   = array("<", ">");
    $content = str_replace($remov, $replc, $content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'apple_news_exporter_content_pre', 'configure_apple_content', 10, 2);
```

For some reason, though, the function is removing the square brackets and anything in them, so:

```
[blue]Blue[/blue] [red]Red[/red]
```

Becomes:

```
Blue Red
```

What I’m after is:

```
<blue>Blue</blue> <red>Red</red>
```

Any help much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you looking at these results in a browser? If so, the browser will interpret `<blue>` and `<red>` as non standard tags and will ignore them, leaving just the text. Try looking at the page source to see what's being sent.

Comment: No, this is being output as JSON by a plugin that grabs whatever is in the post editor.

Comment: The code you have posted here returns the result you expect. See https://3v4l.org/XFkm4 Some basic debugging would have told you that before you posted here. Whatever your problem is, it's elsewhere.